# What uniform is this chap wearing?

Tags: military, uniform

I'm trying to identify the uniform the chap in this photo is wearing.
The photo was taken I believe about WW1 period.
The reverse has the inscription 'The Count' Letta's fiance. I know who Letta is she was born in 1893 and married another chap in 1920.

This is the only photo, it was found in a box of old family photos.

[image: man in military uniform]

Comment: Do you know what country they are serving for?

Comment: No, I know nothing about him. It was suggested he was an Italian Officer. But I know no more.

Answer (score 4):

It does, even without detail, appear to be a photo of a captain in Italian Army service circa WW1 or perhaps shortly thereafter.  The star on the collar is pretty typical, the three plain stars, without any apparent surrounding embroidery, are captain's rank insignia.

*[Wikimedia:Uniforms of Italy](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Military_uniforms_of_Italy_in_World_War_I)* show the collar stars.
*[Wikipedia:Military Ranks of the King of Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_the_Kingdom_of_Italy)* shows the rank insignia.

Comment: Thank you so much this fits in with the families thoughts. Sadly we will never know his real name. But this is wonderful Thanks again.